# Extracting double coordinates form string java

Tags: java, regex, double, coordinates, extract

I'm having a string containing coordinates like this:

```
String coord="-7.21548 1.25434,2.1648 0.154654,..."
```

Where the first double represents x-coordinates, while the second is the y-coordinates. The coordinates are separated by a white space and points with a comma. How can I get those points coordinates in Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Its been asked many times here and it has answer at this community. Its better you [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search) your question or at least review the similar questions drop down as you type your question. You'd better consult [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how you can ask better questions which will be answered quickly. For this particular case, take a look at the page @jhamon mentioned

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
String[] points = coord.split("\\s*[,]\\s*");
```

Where the `split()` method returns an array of Strings.

## Explanation -

```
\\s*   ->  Indicates zero-or-more spaces
[,]    ->  Indicates a comma (which is basically that one present between the points)
\\s*   ->  Indicates that there may be zero-or-more spaces between the comma and the next point
```

---

However, if your text may contain some words, then you would be better off using the Pattern and Matcher class by importing the `java.util.regex` package:

```
String coords = "Hi there! 2.3 12.6786, -1234 7.3, 34 35, are the points!";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9\\-][0-9 .\\-]+(?=,)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(coords);

while(m.find())
    System.out.println("Point found = '" + m.group(0) + "'");
```

Which gives the output of:

```
Point found = '2.3 12.6786'
Point found = '-1234 7.3'
Point found = '34 35'
```

Where `m.group(0)` contains the complete match (point) found.

**Note -** The above method works perfectly *only if the last point's coordinates are followed by a comma*, otherwise it will match the points upto, but not including, the last one.

Comment: Thank you @Coffeehouse for your answer, it works fine

Comment: @OussamaDJIDJ If you feel that an answer has satisfactorily solved your problem, consider marking it as helpful, and even upvote it! This would certainly aid any future references :)